# How to get the Selenium tests in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

**STEP 1**
I installed Java, Eclipse, then installed Selenium,
thanks to this website.
http://www.automationtestinghub.com/download-and-install-java/

**STEP 2**
I got it running thanks to this code:

```
package firstPackage;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeTest {

    @Test
    public void LaunchChrome_method(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");



    }

}
```

Then I added some tests:

```
package firstPackage;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeTest {

    @Test
    public void LaunchChrome_method(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");

        // my first test
        driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("ToolsQA");

        // my second test
        driver.findElement(By.id("sex-0")).click();

        // Unable to locate element
        boolean status = driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).isDisplayed();


    }

}
```

**STEP 3**

but now my question is:

How can I get that "traffic-light" view if tests are failing or passing?

Do I have to install Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is a Continuous Integration server. It is used to do things such as running the suite whenever there is a change in the dev code or running it at predetermined time schedule.

As far as report is concerned, TestNG provides a default html report and saves it by the name "emailable-report.html" inside the test-output folder whenever you run the suite. You can also make a custom report, refer  [this](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testng-customize-emailable-html-report-example) link.

Jenkins also can publish good report using the [Test Analyzer plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin).